# When I try to edit an entry: "Unable to find 'craft\services\EntryRevisions'"

Tags: control-panel, entry, multi-site

I have just moved my site onto the live server and imported my local db. It is a multi-site setup.

In the Entries section of the CP, when I click on an entry to edit it I get the following error page:

> Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
>   Unable to find 'craft\services\EntryRevisions' in file: /home/careacas/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/EntryRevisions.php. Namespace missing?

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you deploy to the live site?  It sounds like some files didn't get deployed properly.

Comment: FTP. I will try again, and install Craft with composer and see what happens. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Be sure and answer back if that solves it! :)

Comment: It did solve it - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace or upload all the files again. A file is not fully uploaded and the reason of this error is that.